# Does the asyncio event loop execution block the code between to await?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I don not understand why in this snippet after inserting a printing statements between 2 `await` tasks, this printing statement is only executed after both `await` statements have been executed.  I was expecting that the printing statement would have shown before the two `await`.

I guess it is due to the implementation of the Event loop ... Is there something special happening between two await, please ?

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)


async def mainex():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
                say_after(4, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
                    say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    print('Is it sequencial ?')
    await task2
    print(f"ended at {time.strftime('%X')}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(mainex())
```

And the output is

```
$ python3 mainex.py                                                                                                     
started at 06:43:10
world
hello
Is it sequencial ?
ended at 06:43:14
```

Answer (score 0):

`create_task()` means "run this coroutine in the background" (while awaiting other things). `await x` means "suspend execution of this coroutine until x completes".

So when you `await task1`, that await waits for 4 seconds because that's how long `task1` takes. After 2 of those 4 seconds, `task2` will have finished, which is why `await task2` is done immediately and both awaits take 4 seconds and not 6. That makes it clear that the tasks were executed concurrently and not sequentially, if that was your question.

If your prints show up late, maybe there is an issue with your IDE and the buffering of standard output? Try running the script in the terminal and see if you get the behavior you expect then.